# How to use velocity for SMS templates

Tags: java, sms, velocity, amazon-sns, template-engine

I am working on a Java service that needs to send SMS through Amazon SNS.

I am using Velocity templates to generate personalized emails, and thought about using it for SMS as well.

But I don't think it is the right approach because the AWS SDK method for sending an SMS takes the message as a string. This would force me to generate a file and then read it to get the contents as a string.

The only alternative I can think of is storing the template as TINYTEXT (SMS size limit is 140 bytes) in the database, and use `String.replaceAll()` instead of velocity.

But I wanted to know if there is a better way to do it or if using velocity would hurt performance that much.

Comment: You can use velocity without generating a file

Comment: You are right, I'm new to velocity templates, and I thought the file was generated by velocity. Now the only question would be if it's better to store .vm files or just a string in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use velocity without generating a file until [VelocityEngine.evaluate](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/app/VelocityEngine.html#evaluate-org.apache.velocity.context.Context-java.io.Writer-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

> renders the input string using the context into the output writer. To be used when a template is dynamically constructed, or want to use Velocity as a token replacer.

[Example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine&method=evaluate):

> ```
> VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
> context.put("param", paramMap);
> context.put("placeList", placeList);
> StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
> ve.evaluate(context, writer, "", template);
> return writer.toString();
> ```